# Learning Python and using dictionaries

Tags: python

I'm working through exercises in [Building Skills in Python](http://homepage.mac.com/s_lott/books/python/html/p02/p02c05_maps.html), which to my knowledge don't have any published solutions.

In any case, I'm attempting to have a dictionary count the number of occurrences of a certain number in the original list, before duplicates are removed.  For some reason, despite a number of variations on the theme below, I cant seem to increment the value for each of the 'keys' in the dictionary.

How could I code this with dictionaries?

```
dv = list()
# arbitrary sequence of numbers
seq = [2,4,5,2,4,6,3,8,9,3,7,2,47,2]

# dictionary counting number of occurances
seqDic = { }

for v in seq:
    i = 1
    dv.append(v)
    for i in range(len(dv)-1):
        if dv[i] == v:
            del dv[-1]
            seqDic.setdefault(v)
            currentCount = seqDic[v]
            currentCount += 1
            print currentCount # debug
            seqDic[v]=currentCount
print "orig:", seq
print "new: ", dv
print seqDic
```

Comment: About your code: The i = 1 assignment is wrong and not used anyway. The range starts from 0, not 1. The '-1' in range(len(dv)-1) is also wrong. Also, you should look at the `enumerate` built-in instead of using range(len(dv)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`defaultdict` is not `dict` (it's a subclass, and may do too much of the work for you to help you learn via this exercise), so here's a simple way to do it with plain `dict`:

```
dv = list()
# arbitrary sequence of numbers
seq = [2,4,5,2,4,6,3,8,9,3,7,2,47,2]

# dictionary counting number of occurances
seqDic = { }

for i in seq:
  if i in seqDic:
    seqDic[i] += 1
  else:
    dv.append(i)
    seqDic[i] = 1
```

this simple approach works particularly well here because you need the `if i in seqDic` test anyway for the purpose of building `dv` as well as `seqDic`.  Otherwise, simpler would be:

```
for i in seq:
  seqDic[i] = 1 + seqDic.get(i, 0)
```

using the handy method `get` of `dict`, which returns the second argument if the first is not a key in the dictionary.  If you like this idea, here's a solution that *also* builds `dv`:

```
for i in seq:
  seqDic[i] = 1 + seqDic.get(i, 0)
  if seqDic[i] == 1: dv.append(i)
```

**Edit**: If you don't case about the order of items in `dv` (rather than wanting `dv` to be in the same order as the first occurrence of item in `seq`), then just using (after the simple version of the loop)

```
dv = seqDic.keys()
```

also works (in Python 2, where `.keys` returns a list), and so does

```
dv = list(seqDic)
```

which is fine in both Python 2 **and** Python 3.  Under the same hypothesis (that you don't care about the order of items in `dv`) there are also other good solutions, such as

```
seqDic = dict.fromkeys(seq, 0)
for i in seq: seqDic[i] += 1
dv = list(seqDic)
```

here, we first use the `fromkeys` class method of dictionaries to build a new dict which already has `0` as the value corresponding to each key, so we can then just increment each entry without such precautions as `.get` or membership checks.

Comment: + 1 Good point about the OP not learning from this by using `defaultdict`.

Comment: Maybe build the list of keys all at once after the dictionary is built: `dv = list(seq.keys())`

Comment: @hughdbrown, if you don't care about preserving the items' order then indeed `.keys` is fine (no `list()` needed in Python 2, and by the OP usage of `print` as keyword we can infer they're using Python 2). But in that case there are other solutions too, let me edit the A to show them.

Answer (score 2):

[defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) makes this easy:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict

>>> seq = [2,4,5,2,4,6,3,8,9,3,7,2,47,2]

>>> seqDic = defaultdict(int)

>>> for v in seq:
...     seqDic[v] += 1

>>> print seqDic
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {2: 4, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1, 47: 1})
```

Comment: If you want to use this method you could use a set to get dv.

Comment: +1 Use defaultdict. In python 3.0+, use collections.Counter. http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/collections.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what you try to do .. count how often each number appears?

```
#arbitrary sequence of numbers
seq = [2,4,5,2,4,6,3,8,9,3,7,2,47,2]

#dictionary counting number of occurances
seqDic = {}

### what you want to do, spelled out
for number in seq:
    if number in seqDic: # we had the number before
        seqDic[number] += 1
    else: # first time we see it
        seqDic[number] = 1

#### or:
for number in seq:
    current = seqDic.get(number, 0) # current count in the dict, or 0
    seqDic[number] = current + 1

### or, to show you how setdefault works
for number in seq:
    seqDic.setdefault(number, 0) # set to 0 if it doesnt exist
    seqDic[number] += 1 # increase by one

print "orig:", seq
print seqDic
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
#arbitrary sequence of numbers
seq = [2,4,5,2,4,6,3,8,9,3,7,2,47,2]

#dictionary counting number of occurances
seqDic = { }

for v in seq:
    if v in seqDic:
        seqDic[v] += 1
    else:
        seqDic[v] = 1

dv = seqDic.keys()

print "orig:", seq
print "new: ", dv
print seqDic
```

It's clean and I think it demonstrates what you are trying to learn how to do in a simple manner. It is possible to do this using defaultdict as others have pointed out, but knowing how to do it this way is instructive too.

Comment: +1 for a more complete answer than mine, and for your `set` comment above.

Comment: The dictionary keys also gives you dv. This is even better than using a set if you're generating the dictionary anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you use Python3, you can use `collections.Counter`, which is essentially a `dict`, albeit subclassed.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> seq = [2,4,5,2,4,6,3,8,9,3,7,2,47,2]
>>> Counter(seq)
Counter({2: 4, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1, 47: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for v in seq:
    try:
        seqDic[v] += 1
    except KeyError:
        seqDic[v] = 1
```

That's the way I've always done the inner loop of things like this.

Apart from anything else, it's significantly faster than testing membership before working on the element, so if you have a few hundred thousand elements it saves a lot of time.